# How can I recursively solve Hanoi Tower with restricted movement?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I've tried to do it and I've searched a lot, but I've not been able to solve this problem. How can I solve Hanoi Tower without moving discs from 'C' to 'B'? I just need the recursion in points, something like this:

(where A is `from`, B is `aux` and C is `to`)

`1. Move N-1 from A to B
2. Move biggest disc from A to C
3. Move N-1 from B to C`

How can I edit this to not use moves from C to B? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't: the general problem has no solution with that restriction.  You need the third post as both temporary storage and destination, with the possibility of moves in either direction; odd disks will revolve in one direction, even in the other.